# Can I see why apt-get install -f is removing my package?

Tags: apt, software-installation, package-management, dpkg

I have a package that I am installing directly from a .deb file by running `sudo dpkg -i`. After running that, I am presented with the list of unmet dependencies for the package. When I run `sudo apt-get install -f` to install the dependencies, `apt-get` instead removes my package without explaining why.

Is there a way to see why `apt-get` is removing my package instead of installing its dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to figure out what was going wrong by running `apt-get` with a debug option:

`sudo apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=true install -f`

This showed why the package was being removed. In my case, `apt-get` couldn't find a certain dependency in the repositories.

Answer (score 0):

From apt-get manual:

```
-f, --fix-broken
 Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place. 
This option, when used with install/remove, can omit any packages to permit APT to deduce a likely solution. If packages are
specified, these have to completely correct the problem.
```

Apparently the only automatic fix detected is removing your package. You should try to solve the dependencies manually.